# The delete statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-delete

How can I write this?

A delete statement to remove all records from the TableA table where the LastName starts with ba and they have a phone number in the 3 area code.

```
DELETE
FROM TableA
WHERE LastName = 'ba' AND PhoneNumber = '3';
```

Comment: Mysql is not the same as SQL server. Please correct your tags

Comment: Hint: Check out `LIKE`.

Comment: Please include sample data for `PhoneNumber`.

Comment: ba, does that include Ba and/or BA?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite are all completely different database products. In all of them though, matching a pattern is done using `LIKE`, not `=`. To match a value that starts with a certain prefix you use `LIKE 'something%'`

`%` matches any character. It's the equivalent of `*` in a file search or `.*` in a regular expression.

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
WHERE LastName LIKE 'ba%' AND PhoneNumber LIKE '3%'
```

Different databases have different case-sensitivity (collation) rules though.

In SQL Server and MySQL, case-insensitive sorting and searching is most common, so `LIKE 'ba%'` will match both `Ba` and `ba`.

In PostgreSQL, the norm is case-*sensitive* matching. You may have to use `[Bb]a%` in that case, to match either `B` or `b`

Comment: `DELETE TableA` is not valid SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is, in SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the phone number column be *text*, then we can use `LIKE` comparisons as follows:

```sql
DELETE
FROM TableA
WHERE LastName LIKE 'Ba%' OR LastName LIKE 'ba%' OR PhoneNumber LIKE '3%';
```